# Implementing XorShift the same in Java and Python

Tags: javascript, java, python, numpy, random

I would like to implement an XorShift PRNG in both Java, Python and JavaScript. The different implementations must generate the exact same sequences given the same seed. So far, I've have not been able to do this.

**My implementation in Java**

have the following implementation of an XorShift PRNG in Java (where `x` is a `long` field):

```
public long randomLong() {
    x ^= (x << 21);
    x ^= (x >>> 35);
    x ^= (x << 4);
    return x;
}
```

If I seed `x` to 1, the first four calls to `randomLong()` will generate:

```
35651601
1130297953386881
-9204155794254196429
144132848981442561
```

**My implementation in Python**

I have tried both with and without numpy. Below is the version that uses numpy.

```
def randomLong(self):
    self.x ^= np.left_shift(self.x, 21)
    self.x ^= np.right_shift(self.x, 35)
    self.x ^= np.left_shift(self.x, 4)
    return self.x
```

With the same seed, the Python function will generate:

```
35651601
1130297953386881
-9204155787274874573 # different
143006948545953793   # different
```

**My JavaScript implementation**

I've not attempted one yet, since JavaScript's only number type seems to be doubles based on IEEE 754, which opens up a different can of worms.

**What I think the cause is**

Java and Python have different number types. Java has 32 and 64-bit integers, while Python has funky big int types.

It seems that the shift operators have different semantics. For example, in Java there is both logical and arithmetic shift, while in Python there is only one type of shift (logical?).

**Questions**

I would be happy with an answer that lets me write a PRNG in these three languages, and one that is fast. It does not have to be very good. I have considered porting C libs implementations to the other languages, although it is not very good.

- Can I fix my above implementations so they work?
- Should I switch to another PRNG function that is easier to implement across prog.langs?

I have read the SO where someone suggested using the java.util.Random class for Python. I don't want this, since I'm also going to need the function in JavaScript, and I don't know that this packages exists there.

Comment: Your XorShift doesn't match the versions presented on Wikipedia. Which variant are you using?

Comment: You can get the Python version to match Java by masking after each shift-left: `self.x ^= ((self.x << 21) & ((1 << 64) - 1))`

Comment: @NayukiMinase: I based it on this code: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/xorshift.shtml#.Vo_h15MrJE4

Comment: @NayukiMinase: I tried your comment as-is. What type did you assume for self.x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would be happy with an answer that lets me write a PRNG in these three languages, and one that is fast. It does not have to be very good.

You could implement a 32-bit [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in 3 languages.

Python:

```
seed = 0
for i in range(10):
    seed = (seed * 1664525 + 1013904223) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    print(seed)
```

Java:

```
int seed = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    seed = seed * 1664525 + 1013904223;
    System.out.println(seed & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var seed = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // The intermediate result fits in 52 bits, so no overflow
    seed = (seed * 1664525 + 1013904223) | 0;
    console.log(seed >>> 0);
}
```

Output:

```
1013904223
1196435762
3519870697
2868466484
1649599747
2670642822
1476291629
2748932008
2180890343
2498801434
```

Note that in all 3 languages, each iteration prints an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Comment: I liked both your and Jaime's answer. I accepted yours based on a coin-flip.

Comment: The Java example code is misleading because there is no unsigned 32-bit int in Java. It takes a Java int seed, but returns a Java long (int & long operation). Half the return values cannot be passed back in to the next seed unless the seed argument is also a long. Casting to int with `System.out.println((int)(seed & 0xFFFFFFFFL));` makes this clear; the results no longer match. For example, the third output (3519870697) cannot be used as as a value for seed in the Java code.

Comment: @JeremyDouglass Your argument is incorrect. Java's `int` type holds 32 bits. These bits are conventionally interpreted as a signed integer. But they can also be treated as an unsigned integer, or even as a floating-point number. In this case, I am treating the `seed` variable as an **unsigned** 32-bit integer. The `+` and `*` operations are identical to the signed version. But the print operation is different, which is why I masked it with `0xFFFFFFFFL` and widened the result to `long` for easy correct results. Either way my algorithm does the right thing, even if the principles are unclear.

Comment: As I said: 1) there is no **unsigned** 32-bit int in Java, and 2) your code returns a long. That isn't an argument -- those are facts. My *opinion* is that this is misleading -- and that is only my opinion, and you may disagree. However, without more explanation, people putting your code in a method may be surprised by the argument or the output or both. This is why I posted a warning. In general, I love your answer, and upvoted it -- highly useful, in all 3 languages! But the Java, IMO, needs more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part is in the logical right shift. The easiest to do in Python if you have access to NumPy, is to store your `x` as a `uint64` value, so that arithmetic and logical right shifting are the exact same operation, and cast the output value to an `int64` before returning, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

class XorShiftRng(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = np.uint64(x)

    def random_long(self):
        self.x ^= self.x << np.uint64(21)
        self.x ^= self.x >> np.uint64(35)
        self.x ^= self.x << np.uint64(4)
        return np.int64(self.x)
```

Those ugly casts of the shift values are required to prevent NumPy from issuing weird casting errors. In any case, this produces the exact same result as your Java version:

```
>>> rng = XorShiftRng(1)
>>> for _ in range(4):
...     print(rng.random_long())
...
35651601
1130297953386881
-9204155794254196429
144132848981442561
```

Comment: I liked both your and Nayuki's answer. I accepted hers based on a coin-flip.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in results between Java and python is due to a difference in how the languages have implemented integers. A java long is a 64 bit signed integer, having the sign in the leftmost bit. Python is... well, different.

Presumably python encodes integers with varying bit length depending of the magnitude of the number

```
>>> n = 10
>>> n.bit_length()
4

>>> n = 1000
>>> n.bit_length()
10

>>> n = -4
>>> n.bit_length()
3
```

And negative integers are (presumably) encoded as sign and magnitude, though the sign does not seem to be set in any of the bits. The sign would normally be in the leftmost bit, but not here. I guess this has to do with pythons varying bit length for numbers.

```
>>> bin(-4)
'-0b100'
```

where -4 in 64 bit 2's complement would be:

```
0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
```

This makes a huge difference in the algorithm, since shifting 0b100 left or right yields quite different results than shifting 0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100.

Luckily there's a way of tricking python, but this involves switching between the two representations yourself.

First some bit masks is needed:

```
word_size = 64
sign_mask = 1<<(word_size-1)
word_mask = sign_mask | (sign_mask - 1)
```

Now to force python into 2's complement, all one need is a logical 'and' with the word mask

```
>>> bin(4 & word_mask)
'0b100'

>>> bin(-4 & word_mask)
'0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100'
```

which is what you need for the algorithm to work. Except you need to convert the numbers back when returning values, since

```
>>> -4 & word_mask
18446744073709551612L
```

So the number needs to be converted from 2's complement to signed magnitude:

```
>>> number = -4 & word_mask
>>> bin(~(number^word_mask))
'-0b100'
```

But this only works for negative integers:

```
>>> number = 4 & word_mask
>>> bin(~(number^word_mask))
'-0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100'
```

Since positive integers should be returned as is, this would be better:

```
>>> number = -4 & word_mask
>>> bin(~(number^word_mask) if (number&sign_mask) else number)
'-0b100'

>>> number = 4 & word_mask
>>> bin(~(number^word_mask) if (number&sign_mask) else number)
'0b100'
```

So I've implemented the algorithm like this:

```
class XORShift:
    def __init__(self, seed=1, word_length=64):
        self.sign_mask = (1 << (word_length-1))
        self.word_mask = self.sign_mask | (self.sign_mask -1)
        self.next = self._to2scomplement(seed)

    def _to2scomplement(self, number):
        return number & self.word_mask

    def _from2scomplement(self, number):
        return ~(number^self.word_mask) if (number & self.sign_mask) else number

    def seed(self, seed):
        self.next = self._to2scomplement(seed)

    def random(self):
        self.next ^= (self.next << 21) & self.word_mask
        self.next ^= (self.next >> 35) & self.word_mask
        self.next ^= (self.next <<  4) & self.word_mask
        return self._from2scomplement(self.next)
```

And seeding it with 1, the algorithm returns as its 4 first numbers:

```
>>> prng = XORShift(1)
>>> for _ in range(4):
>>>     print prng.random()

35651601
1130297953386881
-9204155794254196429
144132848981442561
```

Of course you get this for free by using numpy.int64, but this is less fun as it hides the cause difference.

I have not been able to implement the same algorithm in JavaScript. It seems that JavaScript uses 32 bit unsigned integers and the shifting 35 positions right, the number wraps around. I have not investigated it further.